# how to prevent images from minimizing while we minimize browser window in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I want to get the effects like within the link below. Goto the link and press CTRl-- and see what happens to the images.

```
element.style { 
backface-visibility: hidden; 
height: 1038px; 
position: absolute; 
transform: translate3d(0px, -177px, 0px);
 transform-style: flat; width: 900px; 
}
```

i copied the styling of the website and tried to modified but it seems to have no effect on mine

http://www.beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayH6#up-close

Comment: element.style {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    height: 1038px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate3d(0px, -177px, 0px);
    transform-style: flat;
    width: 900px;
} i copied the styling of the website and tried to modified but it seems to have no effect on mine.

Comment: Well I zoomed in and out of the webpage and the images scaled accordingly, as is what a zoom in and zoom out action is meant for. 

Accessibility. If someone want to zoom in or out of your webpage, it's likely due to that person having sight problems. To prevent that is not, in any case, user friendly.

And since that website zooms in and out correctly in all my browsers (safari, firefox, chrome), I am led to believe that the zooming behaviors you are experiencing are due to some problem with your own browsers...